# m.prop() not working as expected

Tags: mithril.js

Currently I am creating a simple app using `Mithril` and `CoffeeScript`.

The code is as follows:

```
m = require 'mithril'
login = {}

login.controller = ->
    @email = m.prop ''
    @password = m.prop ''
    @onSubmit = ->
        return
    return

login.view = (ctrl) ->
  m 'center.login', [
    m 'aside.logo', m "img[src='/img/logo.svg']"
    m 'article.heading', m 'h3','Enter your email and password'
    m "input.email[placeholder='email'][type='email']",
        onchange: m.withAttr('value', ctrl.email)
        value: ctrl.email()
    m "input.password[placeholder='password'][type='password']"
        onchange: m.withAttr('value', ctrl.password)
        value: ctrl.password()
    m "submit.button button-primary[href='/#/signup']",
        onclick: ctrl.onSubmit()
        value: 'Submit'

  ] 

m.mount document.getElementById('content'), login

module.exports = view: login.view
```

When I run the app, it gives me the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: ctrl.email is not a function

I am thinking the possible reason of the error is because the `mount` function is not configured with the module properly.

Why is the m.prop() not working here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of frustration I finally got the answer.

The error was from a rather stupid blunder.

As I only exported the view, there was no way for the module that `require()`'d the login module of knowing the controller.

I just changed the last line code to

```
module.exports = login
```

and it solved the problem.